# MediaQueries working on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: android, html, css, media-queries

I know that this question was already asked many times but the answers I found did not help.
My media queries are working on desktop just fine, but not on 3 different android devices. Nothing changes, as though MQ were not existing.
I tried using all, screen, screen only. Basically all the options, change my meta tag to what you can see below.

Meta:

```html
 <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_mini.css">
```

> @media handheld, screen and (max-width: 48em) { some style }

This is my first site and I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

Ok, so I spent couple of hours testing and both my devices "think" they have 960px and use media query for this width instead of using smaller MQ.
Doing things suggested here: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972 did not help.

```
html {} 
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
 }
 body {
 font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
 color: #3F4D59;
 background-color: #F2E9DE;
 width: 98%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.flex {
 display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
justify-content: center;
align-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
.top {
flex-direction: row;
order: 1;
background-color: #F2E9DE;
justify-content: left;
align-content: left;
align-items: left;
}
.top {
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
z-index: 1000;
margin: auto;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
filter: alpha(opacity=92);
-moz-opacity: 0.92;
-khtml-opacity: 0.92;
opacity: 0.92;
}
.anchor {
display: block;
height: 200px;
/*same height as header*/

margin-top: -200px;
/*same height as header*/

visibility: hidden;
}
.content {
padding-top: 200px;
}
.header {
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: auto;
align-self: auto;
/*    min-width: 0;*/

min-height: auto;
width: 35%;
text-align: center;
font-size: 3em;
padding: 2%;
} 
.nav {
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: auto;
align-self: auto;
/*    min-width: 0;*/

min-height: auto;
width: 50%;
font-size: 2.5em;
text-align: right;
}
.nav a {
padding: 3%;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
color: #3F4D59;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bolder;
}
a:hover {
color: #9CA1A6;
text-decoration: none;
}
.stamp {
width: 15%;
}
.stamp {
background: url(images/kowalew_ALL.jpg);
display: block;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
/*    text-indent: -9999px;*/
}
.stamp:hover {
background-position: 0 -200px;
}
.offer {
order: 4;
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: auto;
align-self: auto;
min-width: 0;
min-height: auto;
padding-top: 3%;
padding-bottom: 4%;
padding-left: 2%;
background-image: url(images/pea3.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
h1 {
font-size: 2em;
color: #3F4D59;
} 
li {
font-size: 1.4em;
font-weight: 600;
text-align: left;
color: #F2E9DE;
}
.mini-contact {
order: 5;
background-color: #9ca1a6;
flex-direction: row;
}
.mini-contact p {
padding: 0 5%;
font-size: 1.2em;
}
.nolist {
list-style-type: none;
 }
.sectionheader {
text-align: center;
font-size: 2.5em;
font-weight: 800;
flex-direction: column;
background-color: #F2E9DE;
}
.subsectionheader {
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.8em;
background-color: #F2E9DE;
}
.gallery {
flex-direction: row;
background-color: #F2E9DE;
}
.gallery img {
 width: 20%;
 margin: 0.1%;
 border: solid 4px #3F4D59;
 }
.videocontainer iframe {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border: solid 4px #3F4D59;
 }
.gallery img:hover {
 position: relative;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin: auto 0;
 box-shadow: 7px 7px 10px #9ca1a6;
 transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
 z-index: 2000;
 }
.right:hover {
transform: scale(2) translateX(-25%);
}
.left:hover {
transform: scale(2) translateX(25%);
}
.middle:hover {
transform: scale(2);
}
.videocontainer a img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: solid 4px #3F4D59;
}
.video {
flex-direction: row;
}
.videocontainer {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 10%;
padding-top: 135px;
margin-right: 2%;
margin-left: 2%;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
flex-direction: column;
width: 33%;
order: 1
}
.caption {
flex-direction: row;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
}
.caption p {
width: 33%;
padding: 0;
}
.backgroundcon {
background-color: #9ca1a6;
padding-bottom: 4%;
}
.con {
background-color: #9ca1a6;
}
.contact p {
font-size: 1.4em;
font-weight: 700;
 }
.map {
border: solid 3px #3F4D59;
 }
footer {
text-align: center;
padding-top: 3%;
padding-bottom: 2%;
}
/*MEDIA QUARIES*/

@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 85.375em) {
.hide {
    display: none;
}
}
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 64em) {
.header {
    font-size: 2em;
 }
.nav {
    font-size: 1.8em;
 }
.subsectionheader {
    font-size: 1.3em;
 }
.sectionheader {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 300;
 }
 }
 @media handheld, screen and (max-width: 48em) {
 .shide {
    display: none;
 }
 .gallery img {
    width: 25%;
 }
 .contact p {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
 }
.sectionheader {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
.nav {
    width: 60%;
}
.header {
    width: 40%;
}
.content {
    padding-top: 130px;
}
}
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 40em) {
.xshide {
    display: none;
}
.gallery img {
    width: 33%;
}
.top {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav {
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.content {
    padding-top: 130px;
}
}
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 30em) {
.xxshide {
    display: none;
}
.gallery img {
    width: 50%;
}
.offer {
    background-image: none;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
a:hover {
    color: #498099;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li {
    color: #3F4D59;
}
.top {
    background-color: #9ca1a6;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #a7a4a4;
    border: solid 1px #a7a4a4;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.mini-contact {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #a7a4a4;
    border: solid 1px #a7a4a4;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.nav a {
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}
.backgroundcon {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #a7a4a4;
    border: solid 1px #a7a4a4;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.caption p {
    width: 50%;
}
.videocontainer {
    width: 50%;
}
.content {
    padding-top: 80px;
}
 }
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 20em) {
.nav {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: auto;
}
.top {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.xxxshide {
    display: none;
}
li {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
footer {
    font-size: .8em;
}
}
```

Comment: once you  check this
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Checked and nothing changed.

Comment: can you send your demo in jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yymon64j/

Comment: use this
@media (max-width: 768px) {

}

Comment: check it https://jsfiddle.net/q5xvjv4r/

Comment: Still not working on android devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the units of your **max-size**: use `px`instead of `em`.

Here's a example of the code I always use for my media queries, and it always works for mobile devices:

```
@media screen and (max-width : 1024px) {
    /* Change 1024 by what you need. */
}
```

---

Here is the [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) description for `em` unit:

> Relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font)

It's kind of weird to define media queries based on the font-size of your document!

Comment: I used px at first. MQ were not working on mobiles so I changed it to em, just in case (found somewhere, that it worked).

Comment: You can use `screen` and `px` for your MQ, I don't even know if `handheld` is still used...

Comment: Unfortunately, I used screen at the beginning and I didn't work. Then I changed it to other options like handheld.

Comment: What device are you testing with??

Comment: Asus 7" tablet and 5" phone, both android devices.

Answer (score 0):

Your media queries run, they just don't do what you expect. I got a different result using a different screensize, mostly around 30em.  To debug this to find out what is happening you can add  `color: blue` or `color:red` etc to headings or the body tag and the changes then show. Demo [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mousey/4y2Le614/) using edited media queries (to px, with contents replaced with colors) with your HTML and desktop css.

Using `handheld` with a comma means every media query will run for any handheld device, which will probably cause confusing results since the screensize will be ignored, as [explained here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). I've not seen `handheld` used in media queries elsewhere and can't see a reason for using it unless you are handling very large handheld devices that need different css than desktops of the same size.

From your CSS it looks like you might not realize that media queries with `and (max-width: 48em)` and `and (max-width:40em)` will **both** run for screensizes of 40em or less - some lines are repeated in several media queries. If you want the `(max-width:48em)` not to run for smaller sizes as well then you can put something similar to this, although I recommend converting to **px** because otherwise 40.0001em (for example) won't trigger either query:

```
 @media handheld, screen and (max-width: 48em) and (min-width:40.1em) {
 /* code for 40.1 to 48em */
 }
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 40em) {
 /* code for 40em and under */
}
```

The other alternative is reverse anything from a previous media query that is a problem, eg using `display: block` to show something hidden before. Media queries run in the order they are given.

Your code is not [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  as it should be for Stackoverflow -  edit your code down massively and it will help you errors whether you post here or debug on your own**strong text**.